# Dual Y axis line chart in dc.js

Tags: d3.js, graph, charts, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a composite chart of three line charts. One of the charts is using a "fake" group as suggested [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857553/simple-way-to-add-raw-data-to-dc-js-composite-chart-via-ajax/24884871#24884871) As you can see in the snapshot below though the scale of the 3rd chart is very different from the other two. The solution I would like is to have a dual axis chart as shown [here in pure d3.](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/using-multiple-axes-for-d3js-graph.html) I think it can be done using a .renderlet() on the main composite chart but I was wondering if there was a "sexier" solution with pure dc.js?

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

and here is my code. (in coffeescript) I tried using .y and .yAxis on the internal charts but that had no effect.

```
    actualValuesChart = dc.lineChart(mainChart)
        .group(metric, "actual " + @displayName)
        .valueAccessor (d) -> d.value.avg
        .colors(['green'])
        .interpolate('basis-open')

    normValuesChart = dc.lineChart(mainChart)
        .group(metric, "normal " + @displayName)
        .valueAccessor (d) -> d.value.avg_avg
        .colors(['rgba(0,0,255,1)'])
        .interpolate('basis-open')

    clipsCountChart = dc.lineChart(mainChart)
        .group(buildFakeGroup(defaultClipsArray))
        .colors(['red'])
        .interpolate('basis-open')
        # .y(d3.scale.linear().range([100, 0]))
        # .yAxis(d3.svg.axis().scale(d3.scale.linear().range([100, 0])))

    mainChart
        .dimension(@dimension.monthStamp)
        .width(thisChart.width + 30)
        .height(thisChart.width*.333)
        .yAxisLabel(@displayName)
        .elasticY(true)
        .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
        .xUnits(d3.time.months)
        .brushOn(true)
        .legend(dc.legend().x(60).y(10).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .compose([actualValuesChart,normValuesChart,clipsCountChart])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! It's a pretty new feature and I haven't tried it out myself, but if you create some of your subcharts with [useRightYAxis](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#userightyaxis), and then set [rightY](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#rightyyscale) for the second scale on the composite chart, you should get what you're looking for.

But this is totally bleeding edge and I see that the example is currently broken (web/examples/right-axis.html). So please follow up if you run into trouble by [creating an issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/new) or starting a discussion [on the user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!forum/dc-js-user-group).

Comment: Sounds great! I'm assuming that's not in the 1.7 version that I'm using though... Do you know how difficult patching that in would be?

Comment: I'm avoiding switching to the latest dev version since I need to keep my code stable right now

Comment: looking at the source code it seems like this is not as simple as pasting in a new function... I might have to just hack it with a .renderlet() for now

Comment: Ah, right, it's in 2.0.  And in 1.7 the behavior to set the same scale for all children of the composite chart seems pretty hard-wired.  Btw, the series chart in 2.0 might also make your code a little simpler.  Hope to release it by the end of the month.