# dc.js: how to show y axis on both sides of a single line chart?

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I have a simple dc.js line chart. What I want to do is simply show *the same* Y axis on both left and right.

It is quite easy to do on a composite chart with multiple subcharts. This SO question addresses this: [Dual Y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947137/dual-y-axis-line-chart-in-dc-js). And there is [this example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/right-axis.html)

However, I want to have dual Y axis for a *single line chart*.

`^ Y              ^ <- same Y
| single -       |
| line /  \    - |
| -----    \  /  |
|/          --   |
+----------------> X`

Comment: I think the easiest way is just to use a composite chart, and leave the second one blank, and use the same scale for both `.y()` and `.rightY()`

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example [here](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/right-axis.html)
Line 90 in the source for the example uses:

```
.useRightYAxis(true)
```

Comment: Yes, but there are two graphs (and not one). If I use .useRightYAxis(true) on a single graph, I will have a right axis instead of a left axis (and not both).

Comment: Okay I mis-understood your question: you want both a right and left axis for a single line graph.  Perhaps you could have two instances of the same line.  So it will look like one line, even though there are two.