# Dual Y Axis in line chart (dc.js)

Tags: dc.js

Is it possible to add a line for the total sum regardless of shiptype with right Y Axis showing total values something like in image

[image]

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947137/dual-y-axis-line-chart-in-dc-js) question, but there was no answer there.

Here is working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-hoover-d5icn?file=/src/components/LineChart.js) on codesandbox

Comment: Your question is unclear: 1. Usually time is not displayed in the Y axis, are you talking about the X axis? 2. The Right Y Axis feature is normally useful when the units are different in Y, like price and volume for stocks. Total is always the same units as the summed items so it would be an unusual use of this feature, and possibly misleading. Please edit & expand your question.

Comment: You are correct, was little bit tired at a time. Edited question

Comment: It's really close to [this example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/right-axis.html) - did you look at that? You just initialize two line charts into a composite, one with `useRightAxis`.

Comment: Interesting, didn't seen that one. Will give it a test, thanks

Comment: Made it work [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-lake-xbvk6?file=/src/components/LineChart.js). Question, is it possible to make legend item icon to circle? Haven't found that in docs

Comment: Nice. It’s not built in but it probably wouldn’t be hard to hack it with a `pretransition` hook, replacing the `line`s with `circle`s . Please ask another question if you can’t figure it out.